# Errors when I try to build my Java project in VS Code

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code, build

I'm working with Java in VS Code. I imported time4j lib into my project and when I try to compile the project the errors occur:

```
Executing task: gradlew build   -Dorg.gradle.java.home="C:\Users\Public\wpilib\2020\jdk" <


> Task :compileJava FAILED
D:\Scripts\Java\Java_4\src\main\java\frc\robot\subsystems\PID.java:5: error: package net.time4j does not exist
import net.time4j.SystemClock;
                 ^
D:\Scripts\Java\Java_4\src\main\java\frc\robot\subsystems\PID.java:6: error: package net.time4j does not exist
import net.time4j.TemporalType;
                 ^
D:\Scripts\Java\Java_4\src\main\java\frc\robot\subsystems\PID.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        this.clock = TemporalType.CLOCK.from(SystemClock.MONOTONIC);
                                             ^
  symbol:   variable SystemClock
  location: class PID
D:\Scripts\Java\Java_4\src\main\java\frc\robot\subsystems\PID.java:43: error: package TemporalType does not exist
        this.clock = TemporalType.CLOCK.from(SystemClock.MONOTONIC);
                                 ^
4 errors
Compilation Error!
GradleRIO detected this build failed due to a Compile Error (compileJava).
Check that all your files are saved, then scroll up in this log for more information.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

But when I was writing the program there was no any errors and time4j was ok!
I'm new in java and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Why you don't become using IntelliJ? I guess that this error caused by VS Code because it's not a good IDE for coding Java. ;)

Comment: @fr3ddie I know dude :) I just have to write programs by VS Code. I can explain why but it will be too long story.

Comment: You can shortly explain. I'm really interesting why. 

Comment: I'm robot programmer and until this month we have been programming in visual programming lang. So now we have a new conroller fr robots and have some info about how to work with it. The whole info that we have now is on VS Code only. The people who made the controller also wrapped VS Code where you can create a **special** project (with many different build files and smth like that) and work with controller. So I cannot create the same project in IntelliJ :) I hope you understand.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Interesting story :)

Comment: Check the referenced path of time4j and make it right because the error was `package net.time4j does not exist`

Comment: Yes path to .jar file is right (in .classpath file). And I can see the classes of .jar lib in JAVA DEPENDENCIES

Comment: Download the .jar file and copy it to the /libs/ folder in the application project.            Open at the root level of the project build.gradle File and edit the dependency to include the new. Jar file: dependency {compile filetree (DIR: 'libs', include:' *. Jar ')} then rebuild the project. please have a try.

Comment: @MollyWang Thank you very much! It is the solution!

Comment: That's great! I'll write it as an answer~

Comment: Thanks if you mark it as the right answer, and this will help more people reach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check the referenced path of time4j and make it right because the error was `package net.time4j does not exist`;

If it does exist, we can try:

1. Download the .jar file and copy it to the `/libs/` folder in the application project;
2. Open at the root level of the project `build.gradle` File and edit the dependency to include the new .Jar file: `dependency {compile filetree (DIR: 'libs', include:' *. Jar ')}`;
3. Rebuild the project.